# How do I link a dynamic library using node-gyp in linux?

Tags: linux, node.js, node-gyp

I tried adding this to my .gyp file:

```
'link_settings': {
    'ldflags': [
    '-L/path/to/dir', '-lname']}
```

changing *path/to/dir* and *name* to actual values.

However, when I run ldd on the generated .node file, I am not getting the expected link to libname.so.

node-gyp is not ignoring de -L and -l flag, because when I change the library name to one that does not exist, I get an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [reference manual](https://gyp.gsrc.io/docs/InputFormatReference.md) seems to suggest that you need to use `link_settings.libraries` and `link_settings.library_dirs` instead of `link_settings.ldflags`.

Comment: I had already tried that, and I got the same result. In fact I tried, different combinations I read from other people with similar issues and I'm always ending up with the same result.